# How can I render intermediate content in Yii2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, yii2, alternate

My Yii2 based application has a process where I need to fetch data from an external SOAP API and display the results after processing. I wish to display some static data and a placeholder for results until the background process of API data fetch and processing is completed.

Is there a way to display intermediate data in Yii2 views without using Ajax? Ajax is not a suitable option in this case due to amount of data which needs to be exchanged with API, and processed before rendering the results. Plus, results format is variable, and hence different templates may need to be applied before rendering them.

EDIT: to give a clearer picture, the flow is as below:

1. User Submits data (UD)
2. Data is processed onto the server resulting in information (SI) and data (SD)
3. SD is submitting to external SOAP API which returns information (AI)
4. User shall be given the two pieces of information SI and AI, however user shouldn't be able to see the data SD at any point
5. Server side processing takes about 1 second, however API data interchange takes about 15 seconds

So, SI is available at t=1 sec, but AI is only available after t=16 secs. The purpose here is to not make the user wait for AI availability, and give them time to consume SI, while AI is provided when it becomes available.

Comment: What is "intermediate content"? And why simple returning it in controller action will not work?

Comment: Intermediate contents mostly refers to the processed information that is being sent to external SOAP API, as well as some static content describing what to expect in the results. Simple returning it in controller will end the flow then and there, and SOAP API data interchange wouldn't take place. The whole purpose here is to not the make user wait until SOAP API processing has been completed.

Comment: Have edited the original question to add more information around data flow. Hope this clarifies.